# Tkinter winfo_ismapped() method not working

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a program in python which in which I use Listboxes, buttons and labels. So today I came conflicting with a problem. I wanted to make my listbox appear when a button is clicked and disappear when the same button is clicked again. How can I achieve this? I tried using the `winfo_ismapped()` method but didnt seem to work. I think I might have done something crazy. If so, please point it out and give me a corrected answer. Else please tell me a better way to do it.

**My Code:**

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('500x500')
def showMenu():
    overlay = Listbox(root, bg="green",  height=22, width=58)

    if overlay.winfo_ismapped() == 0:
       overlay.place(x=0,y=35)
    else:
        overlay.placeforget()

button = tk.Button(root,text="place/remove", command=showMenu)
button.place(x=0,y=0)

root.mainloop()
```

Actually it comes when I press the button but hide after I press it again.

---

In the same way I have another issue with these labels too.

**CODE:**

```py
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

def placeFun():
    successtext = tk.Label(root, text="Success", anchor='nw',  bg="#212121", fg="#ff3300",font=("Consolas", 15, "bold"))
    if successtext.winfo_ismapped() == 0:
       successtext.place(x=0,y=50)
    else:
        succestext.forget()

button = tk.Button(root, text='place/rem', width=25, command=placeFun)
button.place(x=0,y=0)

root.mainloop()
```

***Please Note***: *I want a professional way to handle this, I said it because, I know a way in which we use variables like:*

```py
globalvartimes = 0

def somefunc():
  if times % 2 == 0:
    show the listbox
    global times
    times += 2
  else:
    remove the listbox
    times += 1
```

*This shows the listbox when `times` is even and remove it when it's odd. 
*These makes the code look non-professional and long.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is every time `showMenu()` is called another `Listbox` is created. To fix that, create the `Listbox` *outside* of the function (so it's a global).

(I also noticed you misspelled the name of `place_forget()` method.)

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('500x500')

def showMenu():
    if overlay.winfo_ismapped():  # Placed?
        overlay.place_forget()
    else:
        overlay.place(x=0,y=35)

overlay = Listbox(root, bg="green",  height=22, width=58)

button = tk.Button(root,text="place/remove", command=showMenu)
button.place(x=0,y=0)

root.mainloop()
```

This looks like it is what is wrong with your `Label` example, too.

Note: If you want to write "professional" code, I suggest you read (and start following) the 
[PEP 8 - Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing out the mistake. And actually I've done correctly in the codes. The misspelling occurred when typing it into here. Thankyou once again.